# Loading DIVs with large images stalls loading of rest of page

Tags: css, performance, html, bxslider

I'm the webmaster of http://concretetoboggan.uwaterloo.ca and a first-time web designer, so I sort of stumbled my way through CSS. I've been having a peculiar problem.

If you go to the link (for the first time), the page stalls for a noticeable 2-3 seconds on the main slideshow before loading the rest of the page. It's really distracting and seems easily fixable, but I can't fix it.

Here's the Net timeline of the site, as you can see, Firebug shows a mysterious gap.
[image]

The sequence of events that the page performs is (supposed to be):

1. Load jQuery at start of page
2. Load page
3. Display the first image of slideshow (the rest of the images are loaded into divs with a 'hidden' class, presumably the browser does this async)
4. Continue loading page
5. Remove 'hidden' class on DOM ready
6. Load jQuery bxSlider on DOM ready

Each of the slideshow slides is composed of a div with an img tag inside and a caption bar sub-div absolutely positioned at bottom:0.

I've tired the following optimizations, which helped slightly-to-not-at-all:

- Remove the table that is loaded below the slideshow (seems to speed things up a bit, still stalls)
- Reduce the size of the images loaded (speeds things up a bit, still stalls)
- Put the img 'src' in a 'dsrc' attribute and then reassign it on DOM ready (still stalls)
- Put the images in background: CSS of div (unwanted layout issues)

Comment: Try to optimize your photos and see if that helps

Comment: @Stephen That is one thing I've tried, all the images are already at 50% quality. But this seems to be a deeper issue, possibly related to the way things are laid out.

Comment: try and remove all your scripts and see which one is causing the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oftentimes, the 'stalling' is due to the page not having sufficient information to calculate the layout, because it doesn't know the dimensions of the images until it's loaded them.

If your happen the know the dimensions of your images, you can avoid this particular problem by changing your `<img>` tags from...

```
<img src="myimage.jpg"/>
```

...to...

```
<img src="myimage.jpg" width="640" height="480"/>
```

...or whatever they happen to be.

However, there are a zillion other reasons why the page might be stalling.

---

**Update**

Another thing that you can sometimes do to speed things up: if you're loading a script with the `<script>` tag which isn't required to render the page, but is only used to process subsequent user input, you can defer the script loading until after the page has rendered by adding the `defer` attribute, e.g. change...

```
<script src="http://someslowsite.com/somescript.js">
```

...to...

```
<script src="http://someslowsite.com/somescript.js" defer="defer">
```

...but if you need the script to render the page, then this won't be possible. If you think the user will be able to load the script from your site faster than a third-party site, then make a copy and host it yourself.

Comment: Alright, I tried implementing your change and it seemed to speed things up greatly (I didn't try this before because I thought the browser wouldn't try and layout hidden elements). There's still a noticable bump though.

Comment: Strange. It loads instantly for me.

Comment: Added a bit more to the answer. IIRC, those are the two things which most frequently block layout. If you really need super-fast speeds, then embed as much of the CSS and JS in the HTML as possible.

Comment: If I wasn't a new user, I would upvote your answer (in addition to checkmarking it) because that was really helpful. I had no idea about the defer command.